# Is it okay to use code from users answers?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I have this [python](/questions/tagged/python) code. It has an issue, so I'm going to ask about it on Stackoverflow.

```python
>>> print "Hello
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.
```

Them user  comes along with the code for the solution to the issue.

```python
>>> print "Hello"
```

Then let's say this code is part of a "**big**" project I've been working on. This project will eventually be published. Is it okay to use the improved/fixed code from the user who answered your question?

Comment: Shouldn't this rather be on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: @AlE I think this applies to most sites that are related to programming, not just Stackoverflow. For example, Codereveiw.

Comment: You should check out the legal link at the bottom of the site. Section 3 in particular deals with using other people's contributions to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is fine to use. The [CC by SA licence](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) explicitly allows commercial usage of code that has been posted.

[image]

In fact common sense should prevail - if a user doesn't want their code used commercially by others then they shouldn't be posting it.

Comment: "Common sense should prevail" in matters of copyright law? That's optimistic :)